# MYSQL query for php web chat message list doesn’t work properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like Below:

```
`id` (message id)
`sender` (username of the person who sent the messages)
`receiver` (username of the person to whome it was sent)
`message` (text content)
`time` (time of the message sent)
`read` (status of the message)
```

I want to display a list of messages sent by or sent to the logged in user `$_session['username']` like Messenger, WhatsApp and so on.
But I am not able to do this anyway. I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `sender`, `receiver` FROM `messages` WHERE `sender`='".$user."' OR `receiver`='".$user."' ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

**The problem is: ** It returns duplicate records and it doesn’t seem to avoid duplicate records which are present in both `sender` and `receiver`

One more point is that I need to save the final list in an array and encode it in json like below:

```
[
{"user":"user1", "message":"hello", "read":true},
{"user":"user2", "message":"hi!", "read":false},
...
]
```

Please help me to do this. I am using simply PHP & MYSQL

★EDIT:

Somehow I ended in this code:

```
<?php
include 'DB.php';
header('Content-Type: application/json');

 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);


$user = $_GET['user'];

$Sql_Query = "SELECT DISTINCT `sender`, `receiver` FROM `messages` WHERE `sender`='".$user."' OR `receiver`='".$user."' ORDER BY `time` DESC";

$check = mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query);
 
if($check){
if(mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0){
        
        $added_user = array();
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)){

         if($user == $row['sender']){
         if(in_array($row['receiver'], $added_user)){

         }else{

  array_push($added_user, $row['receiver']);
         
    }

         }elseif($user==$row['receiver']){
         if(in_array($row['sender'], $added_user)){

         }else{

  array_push($added_user, $row['sender']);
   }

         }

     }
    }else{
        
    }
}else{
}


 

echo json_encode($added_user);
 
 mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The only problem till now is, in the array, it returns the user at the place when he sent his first message. Such as, 
User1 sent u message 1mins ago
User 2 sent u message 30secs ago
User1 again sent u message 10secs ago
It should sort like `{"user1", "user2"}` But it returns `{"user2", "user1"}`

Comment: What query did you try? It seems that it would be fairly simple to retrieve all rows where the logged-in username is the same as the sender, or the same as the receiver. Once you have that query, you can loop through the results and add them to your array, then finally JSON-encode it. Show what you tried so we can suggest why it didn't work.

Comment: I don't want the duplicate records, thats the problem happening

Comment: Are you saying that your database table has duplicate records in it that you want to filter out? Your query above should only retrieve unique combinations of the sender and receiver, so if you have a pair that exchange a lot of messages, they would only appear once.

Comment: Yes, you got it. But somehow, it doesn’t work properly. It doesn’t filter both sender and receiver. And, how can retrieve the other fileds as well as filtering. And, again how can I save the filtered record in a single array?

Comment: The problem with retrieving the other fields / columns is which row should they come from? If you have 100 rows which contain a combination of sender 'hugh' and receiver 'dave', for example, your query will only return one of them (because of the "distinct"), so which of those 100 rows do you want the other columns to come from? Perhaps you need to show some sample data, what you expect out of it, and what you actually get. No point worrying about getting it into an array until you get the data retrieved correctly. If your data has duplicate rows, perhaps better to fix that first?

Comment: Check my last edit Plz

Answer (score 1):

List of messages send by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE sender = '{$session['username']}'
```

List of messages send to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE receiver = '{$session['username']}'
```

List of messages as chat:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE receiver = '{$session['username']}' OR sender = '{$session['username']}'
ORDER BY time DESC
```

If you want to know how to convert it to JSON format, you need to give us more information about your framework, php version and so on.

Comment: But it will not avoid duplicate records like what is done in Facebook or others

Comment: I can not write code for you. I gave you example. If it is not correct give more information

Comment: but you have not gave examples what it should be. everybody know this way.